# IRKernel upgrade R not recognized

Tags: r, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I have anaconda installed and use their version of jupyter notebook. I installed R 
 and IRKernel to make use of R in jupyter.

I can install packages on this version of R (3.5.1) and use them in jupyter.

I have installed a new version of R (3.5.2) using upgradeR() without problems.

To add this version to Jupyter I tried  IRkernel::installspec(name = 'ir52', displayname = 'R 5.2') in R but this doesn't work.

I did this using R in jupyter notebook and this gave no errors and I can select the new kernel.

But when I select the R 5.2 kernel and do 'version' this gives the 5.1 kernel. What have I done wrong?